# Agregar 2 atributos a un div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy agregando un atributo a un div, funciona bien.

Pero quiero agregar 2 atributos pero no se como.

Agradezco su ayuda

```
<div class="claseprueba"></div>
```

```
var product = skuJson_0.productId;
var $addDiv = $('.producto').find('.claseprueba').first();
var $classAdd = $('<div>').addClass('product-page-ret');
$classAdd[0].setAttribute("data-product-id", product);
$addDiv.empty().append($classAdd);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `JQuery` puedes hacerlo de la con `attr`, te muestro un ejemplo:

```
$(myObj).attr({"data-category-name": Category_path, "data-category-other": Other});
```

Toma en cuenta que debes apuntar a lo que represente `$classAdd[0]` en tu caso, asegúrate bien de pasar los valores de manera correcta.

Dejo la documentación de `attr` por si la necesitas: [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Otra manera puede ser con Javascript por medio de un ciclo, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for(var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}
```

Llamarías a la función de la siguiente manera mandando los atributos que deseas:

```
setAttributes(elem, {"src": "http://example.com/something.jpeg", "height": "100%", ...});
```

Te dejo la referencia de esta publicación: [Múltiples atributos en Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274748/setting-multiple-attributes-for-an-element-at-once-with-javascript)

Aquí dejo un ejemplo de como puedes apuntar a tu `div` y agregarle 2 atributos con JQuery:

```js
var $classAdd = $('.claseprueba');

//Aquí cambias el texto Category_path por el valor que tengas, agregué otro atributo "data-category-other" con un valor random solo como ejemplo
$classAdd.attr({"data-category-name": "Category_path", "data-category-other": "OtraValor"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="claseprueba">Ejemplo</div>
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: me sale que attr no esta definida

Comment: Deberías compartir más de tu código, tanto el html como el javascript, ya que con lo que muestras es difícil dar una respuesta tal y como la deseas. Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y agregar el resto de tu código.

Comment: ya esta editada

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo documentado como lo puedes hacer

```js
$( () => {
   
  let val = 0;
  
  // Hacemos el listener
  $( document ).on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  
  // Con el metodo attr() seteamos nuevos atributos, el segundo parametro sera el valor
  $('.prueba').attr( `data${ val }-id`, `value${ val }` );
  
  val++;
  
  // Imprimimos como va nuestro div
  console.log( $('.prueba')[0] )
  
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prueba"></div>
<button>Agregar atributo</button>
```